# Remove product images via script

Tags: magento-1.7, product-images

I want to delete all images from a few products via script. Here is what I got:

```
$mediaApi = Mage::getModel("catalog/product_attribute_media_api");
$items = $mediaApi->items($product->getId());

foreach($items as $item) {
  $mediaApi->remove($product->getId(), $item['file']);
}
```

This works for every image which is in the gallery except one. I just can't delete it. I am pretty sure it is because the last product image is stored for a specific store view. But calling

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($store_id);
```

at the beginning does not help either. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Here are complete steps to remove product images:

**Step 1:**

```
/***Load Products You want to delete product images***/
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('gt' => 500));
```

**Step 2:**

```
$mediaApi = Mage::getModel("catalog/product_attribute_media_api");
```

**Step 3:**

```
foreach($products as $product) {
    $productId = $product->getId();
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
    $items = $mediaApi->items($_product->getId());
    if (count($items) > 0) { 
        foreach($items as $item) {
            $mediaApi->remove($_product->getId(), $item['file']);
        }
        echo 'Product ID: '.$product->getId() . " images removed. \n";
    } else { 
        echo 'Product ID: '.$product->getId() . " image not exist. \n";
    }
}
```